# how to keep checked disabled radioButton in WinForms, C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I have set a radio button to be disabled and checked by default,
but once I opened the window the radio button is unchecked.
force checking the radio button doesn't affect.

Comment: Maybe it *looks* unchecked because it's grayed out. Have you inspected its Checked value, at run-time? A RadioButton's checked status doesn't change by itself. Do you have active DataBindings somewhere? Other RadioButtons are involved? PropertyBindings?

Comment: - Nope, I thought the same, but it is completely empty(unchecked).
- I did check the radio button in compile-time and in run-time as well.
- Both cases causing the radio-button to be unchecked.
- No DataBindigs at all.
- No Other RadioButtons are involved, No PropertyBindings 
:(

Comment: Well, put a BreakPoint in `InitializeComponent()` and follow the sequence of events. Somewhere, you're changing it. Did you print to the Output Window (`Console.WriteLine(myRadioButton.Ckecked);`) to verify its actual value? Or did you subscribe to the `CheckedChanged` event to see if (when) it's raised? Anyway, specify the Visual Studio version and Framework version in use when you have *bug reports* like this.

Comment: What you should also do is to add a new, empty Form to your Project, add a RadioButton to it (or more than one), set it as checked and disabled and open that Form at run-time. See what's what.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Enabled property to false does not disable the application's control box or prevent the application window from receiving the focus.

If you want to force it to checking, maybe you could add a event function when the radio button checked change like below.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = true;
        }
```

[There is describe about control enable (radio button have) in remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Enabled)